# Dockerized React app not recompiling code

Tags: reactjs, docker

I'm trying to dockerize a basic CRA template created through `npx create-react-app project-name`, of which `Dockerfile` would look like:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/client

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I've built the image by running `docker build -t containername .`
and then run it with `docker run -it -p 3000:3000 containername`

Everything works fine, the container runs successfully and I can see the webpage running on the browser.

Problem here is webpack hot reloading not working, causing the app to not recompile upon changes.

Same question was posed already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951752/create-react-app-server-not-recompiling-when-data-changes-inside-docker-containe) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53938476/cant-get-webpack-hotreload-with-create-react-app-and-docker-windows) but sadly with unsuccessful results. Problem seems to appear for Windows users, but in my case I'm on Mac.

I've tried already:

1. Updating `npm start` script with `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true react-scripts start`
2. Adding `EXPOSE 35729` as explained [here](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/how-to-create-react-app-with-docker)

Any suggestion is highly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: It should be possible to install Node and use that as a local development environment with hot reloading and other niceties; you don't need an isolation tool like Docker for this.

Comment: @DavidMaze Could you please explain what you mean by that? And why would that be the case? My idea was to have everything deployable through `AWS ECS`

Comment: You can develop using a local Node environment, package your application in Docker, and deploy it using ECS.  That should all be possible using the same code base, using something like `npm run dev` as you're developing the application and only bringing Docker in when you need to run integration tests or to deploy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievably, the issue was caused by the working directory naming.

In order to fix it, I simply had to change it from `/usr/src/client` to `/app` and it started recompiling, even though I have no clue of the why.

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 2):

i think webpack server doesn't see any new changes, because you modify your local file, but container uses its copies in runtime, which was passed in build time. so you should mount your local dir to container.

i can suggest you use `docker-compose` to mount your work dir from host to container:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  app:
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/client
    ports:
      - 3000:3000 # HOST:CONTAINER
    command: npm start
```

or maybe use `-v $(pwd)/src:/app/src` in run command `docker run ...`

Comment: This is actually what I'm really doing, with related node, mongodb and redis services booting up as well - That works same way, but the react app doesn't recompile

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you actually made me notice I didn't set any volume for it - I've tried with both the docker command including `-v` and a `docker-compose` set up directly inside the client root folder, but still getting it not recompiling

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v ${PWD}:/usr/app -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true globoreactapp/latest
```

Run that on windows poweshell.

If you are using windows cmd, you may try,

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v %cd%:/usr/app -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true globoreactapp/latest
```

And if you are running on some linux distro, you can try something like this.

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true $(pwd):/usr/app
```

So here specifying

> -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true

made the difference for me.

Also with docker-compose, you need to add the same environment variable. Mine looks as follows.

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis-server:
    image: 'redis'
  node-app:
    build: 
      context: ./globoappserver
    ports:
      - "9080:8080"     
    container_name: api-server  
  ui:
    build:
      context: ./globo-react-app-ui
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    ports:
      - "7000:3000"
    stdin_open: true 
    volumes:
      - ./globo-react-app-ui:/usr/app
```